# OpenQA.Selenium - Unable to locate element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code to login in into the site: https://drs.zalohovysystem.sk/

It was working until i uptaded `chromedriver.exe` to version `105`... Now i get error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to
> locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name
> ="E-mail"]"}

```
private void prihlásiťToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
    const string _url = "https://drs.zalohovysystem.sk/";
    const string usr = "";
    const string pass = "";

    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_url);       
    IWebElement Login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("E-mail"));
    IWebElement Password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("Password"));
    IWebElement LoginButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[.='Login']"));
    Login.SendKeys(usr);
    Password.SendKeys(pass);
    LoginButton.Click();

    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "whowhen.txt")))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("WEB:" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }

}
```

Comment: The element is named as `email` not `E-mail` also `Password` should be `password` in HTML attribute values are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong locators.
Try this instead:

```cs
IWebElement Login = driver.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
IWebElement Password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
IWebElement LoginButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']"));
```

Also you will need to add delays to make the elements rendered before you accessing them.
The best way to do that is to use `WebDriverWiats`

Comment: there is still error: no such element: Unable to locate element : {"method":"css selector","selector":":"*[name = "email"]"}
(session info: chrome=105.0.5195.127)

Comment: Obviously because you are missing a delay? Try adding a sleep before this line. If this will help you will need to change the hardcoded sleep to webdriverwait